# math modeling motor control law

Tags: transfer-function, model

I have to model mathematically a motor in matlab and as a state-space and I can't figure out what will be my control variable. I will have a H bridge power electronics.
In order to keept it stable and precise,
Is the current that I need to control in the coils or the voltage ?
Do you have any suggestions for state variables or the model?

Thanks,
John

Comment: First decide on the inputs and outputs of your system.

Comment: We need more detail. Have you been given the motor parameters?

Comment: @Gab, if you want to model a system you need to know what the system is you have to have a representation of it. Like a schematic. Then you use circuit theory and find the currents and voltages and model all the components. Your control variable is what you want to control, if you want to control the velocity in the motor, that is your variable. If you want to control the current in the line to the motor, that could also be a variable. That is up to you. What kind of motor? A BLDC motor will be much different than a brushed.